# Instance member 'log' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, console

I have the following function and try to read the input values `email`and `password`, but I get the following error:

```
  Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {

    Console.log(email);
    Console.log(password);

    final url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/$urlSegment');
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,

            //'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
.
.
.
```

> Instance member 'log' can't be accessed using static access.

What is the problem? Why I can't use `Console.log()` in some points of application to see the value of the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In flutter, we use the print statements to console in the debug.

Like this

```
 print(email);
    print(password);
```

You can also use debugPrint("email": $email) for the text that has more characters.